# Convex Hull of Path Connected sets

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, convex-hulls

This is a pretty easy question to ask, but haven't seen it anywhere.

---

Suppose I have some continuous path $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I want to get the convex hull of $X$, $\operatorname{co}(X)$.

Is it enough to consider only pairwise convex combinations of points in $X$ to generate $\operatorname{co}(X)$? I.e.,

$$\left(\forall z\in \operatorname{co}\left(X\right) \right) \left(\exists\lambda \in \left[0,1\right] \land x_{0},x_{1}\in X \right) \left(z=\lambda x_{0}+(1-\lambda)x_{1} \right)$$

Also, if this is true, is it generalizable to more general topological spaces? Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

This is true in $\mathbb R^2$ but not in higher dimensions. For example, consider a path in $\mathbb R^3$ that lies in the half-space $z\ge 0$ and touches the $xy$-plane at three non-collinear points. The convex hull contains the solid triangle spanned by these points, but pairwise convex combinations only give you three segments in that plane.

Answer (score 12):

No, it is not enough to consider convex combinations of pairs of points in the connected set. A famous example is the moment curve $(t,t^2,t^3,\dots,t^n)$ where when you take the convex hull all convex combinations of [n/2] points form a face of the convex hull. Caratheodory theorem asserts that for every $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ a point in the convex hull of X is in the convex hull of $d+1$ points from $X$. I vaguely remember that when $X$ is connected you can replace $d+1$ by $d$ but I am not sure about it.

Added later: Indeed it is an old theorem that you can replace $d+1$ with $d$ when $X$ is connected. A recent theorem of Barany and Karasev assets that if $X$ is a set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the property that all projections of $X$ into a $k$ dimensional space are convex, then every point in the convex hull of $X$ is already in the convex hull of $d+1-k$ points from $X$.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no.   For example, it's fairly easy to draw a knot $S^1 \to \mathbb R^3$ such that the convex hull is not the same thing as the set of all secants.  If you want a concrete example, take a standard parametrization of a trefoil, so that the origin is the intersection of two axis of symmetry.  You'll see the origin is in the convex hull, but its not on the set of secants.

Comment: Dear Ryan, your answer came 13 seconds before mine.

Comment: Dear Gil: and your answer is more concrete than mine.  

Comment: all three answers are nice and rather different.. i never thought about the convex hull of the standard realization of the trefoil, looks interesting.

Comment: The geometry of the the convex hull of a smooth knot has some connections to finite-type invariants (via my work with Conant, Sinha and Scannell).  It's also connected to rope-length geometry / packing type problems for knots, via work of John Sullivan, Kusner, Cantarella, Denne and that group.  

Comment: Interesting! There are some recent and not so recent interest in convex hull of curves and higher dimensional objects embedded in R^n. (The link to the paper Ryan mentioned are http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0303034.) 

Comment: And here is the Cantarella, Kuperburg, Kusner and Sullivan reference that I was thinking of, but forgot to accurately cite: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0204.5106

Comment: The link in [Ryan's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77379/convex-hull-of-path-connected-sets/77381#comment198468_77381) is broken, here's a replacement: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204106

Answer (score 3):

This is just a computational footnote to the thrust of this old question, but
I wanted to mention that finding the convex hull of a polygonal path is
computationally easier in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that finding the hull of unconnected
points: It can be computed in $O(n)$—linear time—compared to the $\Omega(n \log n)$ lower bound for unconnected points:

> Melkman, Avraham A. "On-line construction of the convex hull of a simple polyline." *Information Processing Letters* 25, No. 1 (1987): 11-12.
>   ([ACM link](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=31183).)
>
> ---
>
> [image]
>   
>             
>   
>   <sup>Image from Joe Mitchell's course notes: 
>   [PDF download](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~jsbm/courses/345/13/melkman.pdf).</sup>

---